# Does the Pali word "sattā" mean "sentient beings"?

Tags: pali-canon

The new Sutta Central translations have translated the Pali word "sattā" as "sentient beings", as follows:

> *And what is rebirth? Katamā ca, bhikkhave, jāti?*
>
> *The rebirth, inception, conception, **reincarnation**, manifestation of the aggregates, and acquisition of the sense fields of the various
>   **sentient beings** in the various orders of **sentient beings**.*
>
> *Yā tesaṃ tesaṃ **sattā**naṃ tamhi tamhi **satta**nikāye jāti sañjāti okkanti **abhinibbatti** khandhānaṃ pātubhāvo āyatanānaṃ paṭilābho.*
>
> [*SN 12.2*](https://suttacentral.net/sn12.2/en/sujato)

What evidence is there in the Pali suttas that the word "sattā" means "sentient beings"?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it is, if the sentient beings means dukkha-khandha (being) which still cycle-processing (sentient;paṭiccasamuppāda).

The being of asañña-satta is in the cycle processing, but asañña-satta has not nāma-paṭiccasamuppāda, so "sentient" shouldn't means sentiency. See Sutta. Aṅ. (4): sattaka-aṭṭhaka-navakanipātā [sattāvāsasutta](http://www.84000.org/tipitaka/read/v.php?B=23&A=8534&Z=8558&eng=suttacentral):

> There are sentient beings that are non-percipient and do not experience anything, such as the gods who are non-percipient beings.
>
> Santi, bhikkhave, sattā asaññino appaṭisaṃvedino, seyyathāpi devā asaññasattā.